# Cross Platform image editor with comments support for studying with tutor remotely

Tags: document-management, image-editor

I need to find something like **Google Docs** but for images.

On my side, I have a regular printed study book. To do homework I take a picture of a page and draw/type over this image and then I send it to my private tutor by email. It looks like so:

[image]

What I want is that both of us can edit images: leave marks, draw something simple, strike through the text and so on. Also, need comments that can be attached over on the image and file syncing.

I use MacBook and as a web developer I would love to use **Figma** but my teacher uses iPad and there is no app for iPad. There is a **Photoshop** for iPad coming but there is no comment support. The question is... is there anything else like this?

I was thinking maybe to look on the PDF side? Is there any way to edit and comment PDF files? Or maybe software that people use to draw with Apple Pencil? What apps do people use when they take iPads to the class?

Thanks.